# Configure PyCharm to make the linting work properly

Tags: python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying to use PyCharm with a Python ROS node. The linting displays the message `No module named [...]` for all the imports related to ROS (rospy, std_msgs, tf, ...). It seems that I selected the right version of Python, but rospy and the others don't appear:

[image: image description]

I think I have to tell PyCharm to look in `/opt/ros/kinetic/share`, but I don't know how to do that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304101/configure-pycharm-to-make-the-linting-work-properly/) by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From terminal:

```
$ source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
$ pycharm-community
```

I went ahead and [added `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` to the bottom of `~/.bashrc`](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#kinetic.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup).

---

Edit: To run PyCharm via application shortcut...

1. Find PyCharm .desktop file:
   `$ locate .desktop | grep pycharm`
2. Open the PyCharm .desktop file:
   `$ sudo -H gedit /PATH_TO_PYCHARM_DESKTOP_FILE/PYCHARM_DESKTOP_FILE.desktop`
3. Add `bash -i -c` to the `Exec=...` line within the desktop file.
4. Save and exit.

---

Example (Ubuntu 16.04, PyCharm Community 2018.2.4):

```
$ locate .desktop | grep pycharm  
$ sudo -H gedit /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop
```

**pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop**

*original:*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=/snap/pycharm-community/85/bin/pycharm.png
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop /snap/bin/pycharm-community %f
Comment=Python IDE for Professional Developers
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
```

*edited:*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=/snap/pycharm-community/85/bin/pycharm.png
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop bash -i -c /snap/bin/pycharm-community %f
Comment=Python IDE for Professional Developers
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
```

---

References:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/204326/pycharm-setup/?answer=265410#post-id-265410
- https://askubuntu.com/a/913536
- https://superuser.com/questions/202676/sudo-vs-gksudo-difference/726249#726249

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-09-24**:
Thanks. In fact, I had already sourced `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` and `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` in `~/.bashrc`. So I just needed to run PyCharm from the console. Your solution is surely more elegant than mine. The only drawback is that I can't run PyCharm with the shortcut that way.

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2018-09-24**:
I edited answer with method that should allow you to run PyCharm via shortcut.

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-09-25**:
Thanks! It works well.

**Comment by [sxin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25682/sxin/) on 2018-11-28**:
It works for me, ubuntu 18.04 and ros melodic.

**Comment by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on 2019-11-30**:
Hello, it did work for ubuntu 18.04 and melodic, for a while --- but I just reinstalled a new computer, and it seems that adding bash -i -c ... strangely works the first time, and after that it will still run, but everything will be in background. ps aux | grep pycharm will show a process, but no output on the screen.

Best regards,
C.